# How to save two records via API POST route in node js express

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I have this api route function that needs updates a topic record to include a reference of post, then save the actual post record being created. Is there a better way to do what i want to do? is it possible?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/:id/posts',  (req,res) => {
  const newPost = new Post({
      post: req.body.post,
      description: req.body.description,
      topic_id: req.params.id
  });
   Topic.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(topic => {
          topic.posts.push(newPost._id);
      })
          .catch(err => {
              res.send(err);
          });
  //how do i save this topic record I find and push an id into.


  newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));
});
```

github line 33: https://github.com/wolffles/bloccit-node/blob/express/routes/api/topics.js

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: mongoose is an ODM ill edit post to have more resources

Comment: Okay. Try my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**

How do you save the topic record you found and modified?

**Answer**

Try this out with the latest JS async await syntax.

```
router.post('/:id/posts',  async (req,res) => {
  const newPost = new Post({
      post: req.body.post,
      description: req.body.description,
      topic_id: req.params.id
  });
  try {
     await Topic.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
       doc.posts.push(newPost._id);
       doc.save();
     });
     const post = await newPost.save()
     res.json(post)
  } catch(err) {
     res.send(err)
  }
});
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of null

Comment: Modified solution. Try one more time.

Comment: ah very nice its exactly how i wanted it to respond.

Comment: Great! Happy I could help.

Comment: I'm not used to these methods are they just plain javascript? where can i read up more about them?

Comment: Which methods are you referring to specifically?

Comment: i've seen a majority of others use async,await but the way i was taught in a simple youtube video i never saw the person use these.

Comment: Ahh okay. So it's part of the javascript language now and just makes managing promises a bit easier. So as opposed to doing .then for the everything, this just makes it easier to read. 

So you can only use await inside of a function that you've prefixed with async (as shown in my solution). Await is essentially just saying, WAIT for this promise to resolve, THEN move on to the next line. 

The MDN documentation on this is actually quite nice.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score -1):

Just save the document in the promise success of the topic return. Just like i wrote below.
Let me know if that works.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/:id/posts',  (req,res) => {
  const newPost = new Post({
      post: req.body.post,
      description: req.body.description,
      topic_id: req.params.id
  });
   Topic.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(topic => {
          topic.posts.push(newPost._id);
          //now update the newPost
          newPost.topicObj = topic;
           newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));
      })
          .catch(err => {
              res.send(err);
          });
  //how do i save this topic record I find and push an id into.


 
});
```

Comment: very close but the Topic.findById is actually like a parent record, and we're just trying to save the newPost._id in Topic.post. here you've added a new attribute newPost.topicObj which already exist when creating newPost

Comment: Then, do it the other way, in the callback of save() method, write the code Topic.findById() and then update the topic and topic.save()  this way , you have inserted the post and got the post._id in the callback, you can use it to update the topic with the values you want to.